# Sending File through database Mail

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to sending a file through Database mail , when i execute the query below without @query option mail is triggered but when i include the @query option i get the error mentioned.

```
    if @@rowcount >0
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail     @profile_name = '     Errormail',@recipients='arunkumarb@mobiusservices.in;',
    @subject = 'A new Record created in the SSORunError Log Table' ,
    @body = 'A new Record created in the SSORunError Log Table' ,  
    @query = 'select * from ip',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
    @query_result_width = 4000, 
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Details.txt'
```

**Error Message :**

```
    Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
      Error formatting query, probably invalid parameters
     Msg 14661, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 504
      Query execution failed: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Server  , Line 1
      Invalid object name 'ip'.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using fully qualified name for the table:

```
SELECT * FROM yourDatabase.yourSchemaName.ip
```

You can also set `@execute_query_database` parameter of your call to `sp_send_dbmail` to contain the name of your database (although I think that using fully qualified name should be enough).